# Optional String Match in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a code in Python 2.7 which is used in finding information from a flight in a given piece of text. They always come grouped (operators have a standard format and just fill in the blanks and send the message)

```
import re

line = "JetMobile:Your flight 9W448 on 14Jan2015 is expected to leave BLR at 19:00 hrs, reach BOM at 20:42 hrs. Download our Mobile App from http://m.jetairways.com/mobileapps for booking(s), flight status, check-in and more."

matchObj = re.match( r'JetMobile\:Your flight (.*?) on (.*?) is expected to leave (.*?) at (.*?) hrs, reach (.*?) at (.*?) hrs\. Download our Mobile App from (.*?) for booking\(s\), flight status, check-in and more\.', line, re.M|re.I)

if matchObj:
   print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.group()
   print "matchObj.group(1) : ", matchObj.group(1)
   print "matchObj.group(2) : ", matchObj.group(2)
   print "matchObj.group(3) : ", matchObj.group(3)
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

However I want to match

```
"JetMobile:Your flight 9W448 on 14Jan2015 is expected to leave BLR at 19:00 hrs, reach BOM at 20:42 hrs. Download our Mobile App from http://m.jetairways.com/mobileapps for booking(s), flight status, check-in and more."
```

and also

```
"JetMobile:Your flight 9W448 on 14Jan2015 is expected to leave BLR at 19:00 hrs, reach BOM at 20:42 hrs. Download our all new Mobile App from http://m.jetairways.com/mobileapps for booking(s), flight status, check-in and more."
```

How do I do it?

Comment: So whats wrong with your code?

Comment: I cant match if there is "all new". So i wnat to change regex to match that

Comment: Just make it optional! within a none capturing group `(?:all new)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `all new` optional with `?`. Use the following::

```
matchObj = re.match( r'JetMobile\:Your flight (.*?) on (.*?) is expected to leave (.*?) at (.*?) hrs, reach (.*?) at (.*?) hrs\. Download our (?:all new )?Mobile App from (.*?) for booking\(s\), flight status, check-in and more\.', line, re.M|re.I)
```